# Generic type in inner class

Tags: java, nodes

I have an outer class (`LinkedStack<T>`) that has an inner node class. Is it necessary to declare the inner Node class with the same generic like

```
private Node<T>
```

as opposed to

```
private Node
```

or does it not make any difference?

Comment: The answer is really "it depends," but I would personally use the same generic on the inner class, for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inner class is a static class then yes, otherwise no.

I.e.:

```
class LinkedStack<T> {
    // references to T refer to LinkedStack's T.

    static class Node<T> {
        // references to T refer to Node's T.
        T data;
    }

    // ...
    Node<T> node;
}
```

or:

```
class LinkedStack<T> {
    // references to T refer to LinkedStack's T.

    class Node {
        // references to T refer to LinkedStack's T.
        T data;
    }

    // ...
    Node node;
}
```